# PHP How to echo the result of a fetch outside a while-loop

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I am new to Object Oriented PHP. Currently I am making a login script and am stuck at fetching & echo'ing the results. This is my script:

```
$stmt = $db->mysqli->prepare("select User from `users` where User = ? AND Password = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$num = $stmt->num_rows;
$stmt->bind_result($username);

if ( $num !== 1 ) {
    echo 'no result';
} else {
    echo 'Your username: '. $username ;
}

$stmt->close();
```

As you can see I am not fetching a result in the script above. I tried using `$stmt->fetch()` in a while-loop prior to the `$num !== 1`.

However, the result of the fetching is "stored" as an array (I think), even though inside the while loop you don't use an array (just `$username`). **What I want:** echo the result of the select query OUTSIDE a while loop. Just as it is possible in the old fashioned way (assuming there is only 1 result, therefore no while-loop necessary):

```
$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $query );
$record = mysqli_fetch_array( $result );
echo $record['username'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to accses to object variable:

```
echo $stmt->User;
```

Or you can save variable for later:

```
$user = $stmt->User;
```

After ending of your loop your `$user` will hold the value.

Comment: Had no joy with the `$stmt->User`, saying the property didn't exist. I replaced it with just `$username` and that worked. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$stmt->get_result()` to do that, e.g.

```
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

$record = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $record['username'];
```

Edit

Another method is to call fetch after bind_result

```
$stmt->bind_result($username);
$stmt->fetch()

echo $username;
```

Comment: I tried that, but I get an error that the method doesn't exist. According to PHP.net it's only available with mysqlnd. Not sure what that is but apparently something I don't have.

Comment: You're right, I've edited the answer to include another method without that dependancy.

Answer (score 0):

Old fashion way:

```
print_r($record);
```

From the php manual: [print_r](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)